# Git push to multiple repos prints "fatal: a task was canceled" and takes about 10 minutes to complete

Tags: git, git-remote, multiple-repositories

I am attempting to push commits to multiple remote repositories at once. My approach (which is described [here](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242)) is to set the remote push url origin to both 2 repos and do the git push command.

However, the push process takes quite a long time to complete (approximately 10 minutes) and it also prints to the console "fatal: A task was canceled" as the image below [image].

Thanks for reading, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands

git config --system --unset credential.helper
git config --global credential.helper wincred

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).